# msg object is not readable info

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-red

Good day people of Stackoverflow...

I have a serious problem with the info I`m reading of my weather API.

I get info into a function node that exports the sunset and sunrise times,
now the problem is that it gives me the info in a weird way.

EG. Object:

sunrise: 1572060152

sunset: 1572106754

now if I click on the number it changes to a HEX. And if I click on it again it changes to something else, not sure what u call it but it looks like this "2019-10-26T03:22:32.000Z"
And then if I click it again I get the info that I require **10/26/2019, 5:32:32 AM [UTC+2]**

I need to get the time extracted from that info but it doesn't matter what I try the outcome is always the 10 digit number...

Please help.

Comment: How do you get this info from the API? Each time you click the values the `node-red` converts it to a different representation. The second one is the ISO format.

Comment: I'm using a weather node that I installed "node-red-node-openweathermap". so when I request data from the server it gives me a five-day forecast in a msg:object with msg.payload msg.location everything.

Comment: And did you read about what does this weather API returns to you? It could be the time in milliseconds, but I'm cannot be sure if you don't provide more info about it.Be more specific, paste the whole object response, for example

Comment: It returns a json object to me. with so much info

Comment: I don't understand your question? 1572106754 is a timestamp, what is the expected result?

Comment: Read up on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

The OpenWeather node is returning timestamps in what is known ans [epoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format. Epoc time is the number of seconds since 1st January 1970. This is basically how all computers work with time.

The Node-RED sidebar is just being helpful, in that when it sees a number that is in the right range, it will automatically convert it to different things when you click on it, in this case it is converting first to a hex representation (0x5DB47202) and then to a human readable timestamp (using what ever timezone your browser is using).

What you do with that value entirely depends on what you are going to do with it next, but assuming you want to display it to a user somewhere (e.g. in the Dashboard UI) then have a look at the [node-red-contrib-moment](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-moment) node as this has lots of options for working with timestamps and converting them into other formats.